# Swift socket.io compatible version with server python-socketio

Tags: python, ios, swift, socket.io, flask-socketio

I've searched couple of days for it but found nothing to fix this issue.

My client is an iOS device running socket.io v15.2.0 (Oct 17, 2019).

I've followed this post ([Implement a WebSocket Using Flask and Socket-IO(Python)](https://medium.com/swlh/implement-a-websocket-using-flask-and-socket-io-python-76afa5bbeae1))

That post described how to connect to the python socket server with a javascript client but even the javascript client has also returned same error :|

Then I checked the compatibility table at [this page](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio) and found out that the latest version only works with the javascript client versions of 3.x so I checked [this website](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io) to see the latest version of javascript socket.io client and I changed the version to 3.0.4 then the JS client successfully connected to the python socket server .

BUT, there is no versioning table for **iOS clients** at the swift socket.io [Github page](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift)

Is there any versioning table for iOS/Android clients to show which **python-socketio** version is compatible with the v15.2.0 of swift socket.io clients?

Error:

```
The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Dec/2020 13:29:15] "GET /socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1 HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Comment: There are really two recent versions of Socket.IO, the 2.x and 3.x in JavaScript version numbers. If your client does not work with latest one, then it'll likely work with the previous one, so try to downgrade the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after testing many different version finally found the correct versioning to work with swift socket.io `15.2.0`
here is the versions:

```
tornado==5.0
Flask-SocketIO==1.0.0
python-engineio==2.2.0
python-socketio==2.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

updated as today:

if you use `python-socketio-5.7.1` as server, you need to update `Socket.IO-Client-Swift 16.0.1`